# How to create array with key => values from object{key, value}?

Tags: php, laravel

I solver this by this code

```
    $service_list = Service::all();
    $services = [];
    foreach ($service_list as $item){
        $services[$item['id']] = $item['name'];
    }
```

but how to do that using php_array functions?
its for dropdown select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you have to use PHPs built in array methods but we have `pluck` on the Query Builder and Collection class.

```
$services = Service::pluck('name', 'id');
// $services->all(); // for the actual array contained
```

This will only select the `name` and `id` in the query and give you a Collection keyed by the `id` only containing the `name` field.

```
$services = Service::all();
$services_array = $services->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
```

If you already have your collection of models (code above has queried for every field and hydrated models with the result) you can use `pluck` on the Collection to achieve the same result (though less efficient as it had to query for all fields, hydrate models, then pull those 2 fields from them)

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results)

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Collections - pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck)

Answer (score 1):

Use `toArray()` to convert the collection to an array, then use `array_combine()` to create an associative array from that.

```
$service_list = Service::all()->toArray();
$services = array_combine(array_column($service_list, 'id'), array_column($service_list, 'name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$service_list = Service::all()->toArray();
```

`all()` will return a `collection`. The `collection` supports a `toArray()` method

Comment: I think this will create a 2-dimensional array, not an associative array.